# trying to call a variable inside a function in php

Tags: php, database, global-variables

I wanna program a function that shows elements of my data base according to the input I enter

Here is my code but I got an error on the line 34

> Notice: Undefined index: table[1]["des_dem"] in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gpc\test.php on line 34

```
<?php
$element  = $_GET["element"];
echo $element;

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpc";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// $sql = "SELECT * FROM bons WHERE des_dem='$element'" ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bons" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$table = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

} else {
echo "0 results";
}/*
echo $table[1]["des_dem"];
echo "<br>";
echo $table[1]["des_dec"]; */

function afficher()
{
    echo $GLOBALS['table[1]["des_dem"]'];
}
echo $table[4]["des_dec"];
echo "<br>";
afficher();

$conn->close(); ?>


<html>
<body>

<br>
<form action="test.php" method="get">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="element"></td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for answering my questions :)

Comment: this should be: `echo $GLOBALS[$table[1]["des_dem"]];`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `global` keyword to do this, you cannot call it within the $GLOBALS array like that, do this..

```
function afficher()
 {
     global $table;
     echo $table[0][1];
 }
```